# Is there any style framework for react-native similar to bootstrap for web?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Ionic is awesome, but if you want to stay in the React-native world, I haven't found anything comparable and compatible. Let me know if you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the use of React-native essential for you? If you just want to use React with Ionic have a look at my open source project here: https://github.com/pors/reactionic/

Comment: you can check this https://codecanyon.net/item/react-native-bootstrap/19244728. It has all missing components with great look and feel.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-bootstrap/react-native-bootstrap

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The closest thing is going to be material design https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit which is pretty great. At this time there is no bootstrap for react native, not to say that it isn't coming down the pipeline one day.

Comment: Can [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) be used with React Native?

Comment: @Marklar No. React Bootstrap uses DOM elements which don't exist in a React Native environment

Comment: This seems to be a bad choice, since it's not actively maintained anymore: https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit/issues/380

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootstrap-styles is an alternative

Answer (score 37):

Disclaimer: I own [NativeBase.io](http://nativebase.io/) and [Native Starter Pro](http://strapmobile.com/native-starter-pro/).

My team built Native Start Pro - [Premium React Native starter](http://strapmobile.com/native-starter-pro/) kit to quickly get off the ground on your next mobile app projects.

It includes

- Customizable variables just like Bootstrap
- Components like Contact list, Login screen, Simple forms, Slide-in menu, Inbox view, Compose Email, View Email

It also comes with a [detailed documentation](http://strapmobile.com/native-starter-pro-docs/docs.html).

---

We Open-Sourced many components from [Native Starter Pro](http://strapmobile.com/native-starter-pro/) as [NativeBase.io](http://nativebase.io/) which is getting huge popularity on [ProductHunt](https://www.producthunt.com/tech/nativebase)

Answer (score 19):

This project is aiming toward this direction:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements