# React native styling flex framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Good day for you all ,

i am asking if there is any kind of styling snippets or libraries for react native components that i can use like boostrap or fontawsome ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon! I think this is something you might want to take a look at, https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit, seems to be what you're looking for.

I also found this similar post if you want some more details: [Is there a react-native style framework similar to bootstrap for web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550323/is-there-a-react-native-style-framework-similar-to-bootstrap-for-web)

Hope this helps, have a great day!

Comment: thank you so much for sharing ur knowledge